# MacOS docker hanging on config file

Tags: macos, docker

I have edited the my docker preferences in the advanced section, where you can paste in JSON and restart. I have added the below and the application never starts, it says to reset if it hangs (which I do) but gives me no cause as to why it hangs.
checking the documentation my JSON looks valid.

config as per the below:

```
{
  "experimental" : true,
  "bip" : "192.168.16.1/20",
  "debug" : true,
  "default-gateway" : "192.168.17.1",
  "dns" : [
    "10.50.0.1"
  ],
  "fixed-cidr" : "192.168.17.0/24",
  "ip-forward": true
}
```

and the attached screen
[image: docker settings]

I've tried it with just the two settings it doesn't work still. I tried it with fixed-cidr on its own, it was accepted but the change didn't reflect in my image, the machine was still on its default 172.17.0.0/16

EDIT:
ok settings have been accepted as per the below:

```
{
  "experimental" : true,
  "bip" : "192.168.16.1/20",
  "debug" : true,
  "default-gateway" : "192.168.17.1",
  "dns" : [
    "10.50.0.1"
  ],
  "fixed-cidr" : "192.168.17.0/24"
}
```

however the bridge is now not working, I cannot ping from my VM outside the VM network, do I need to do something additional to nat the new bridge (was a new bridge created when I did this or was the original edited?)

Thanks

Comment: remove each setting one by one and see which one is the one causing issues

Comment: @TarunLalwani tried this no luck, as per the above, with just two settings

Comment: WRT the edit, I'm not sure how docker comes into play with the VM. Can you explain the full setup?

All I can say is, have you created conflicting networks? Is 192.168.2.1 actually on the same bridge? Why are you changing the default gateway?

Comment: is the default-gateway the gateway for the VMs? if yes then that needs to be in the same subnet as the cidr, then the bridge needs to also be in the same subnet or in its own?. basically I just need the VMs on a different subnet as it is overlapping some internal networks

Comment: If all you need is to have the docker0 bridge on a different subnet, then you can use just `--bip` and no other options... so something like `--bip 10.10.0.1/16` or whatever makes sense for your setup.

Comment: @cpuguy83 its the VMs I need on a different subnet the default 172.16.0.0/16 overlaps with some of our internal networks I need the VMs to be able to access

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Setup the VM's as needed and configure `--bip` with the address space you want.

Comment: the default VM subnet is 172.16.0.0/16 I need the VMs to be on 192.168.2.0/24 instead. thats it really, is that easy to do?

Comment: By VM I'm assuming you mean container?

Comment: yeah container sorry

Answer (score 0):

There issue would seem to be with your usage of `default-gateway`.
There are a few settings here that you need to set.

The `default-gateway` setting needs to be within the IP range being used for the default range.
Now you did provide the `fixed-cidr`, however if you previously started dockerd with a different range, the docker0 bridge will still exist or even be created with the range it was originally created with.

If you provide a `bip` option this should clear it up, but note that the option needs to be within the range of your `default-gateway`.
Also note the original configuration you posted is incorrect as you have the bip set to `192.168.1.5/24` but the gateway is `192.168.2.5` and the `fixed-cidr` is in that same range.

Comment: so the bip needs to be within the fixed-cidr also? for example, bip 192.168.2.1 gateway 192.168.2.2 and cider 192.168.2.0/24?

Comment: I have updated the original question with the latest problem I you could help?

Comment: The bip needs to be in the same subnet as the fixed-cidr, but not the same range. The point of `fixed-cidr` is to specify a range that is smaller than the bridge's subnet.

For example you can do `--bip 192.168.1.1/16 --fixed-cidr 192.169.2.0/24`, which puts the bridge on a full /16, but only allocates a /24 for container IP's.

Comment: I've edited the config as per your notes and it has been accepted but I cannot ping outside the VM still, how do I troubleshoot this?